# recycleview setadapter for specific position

Tags: java, android, android-recyclerview, android-asynctask, jsonhttpclient

I have created a "horizontal listview" by using `Recycleview`.

Since I have `async` task in my program I cannot retrieve from fetchbook class the book result and therefore I need to set the adapter inside the class.

My code looks as follows:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate( savedInstanceState );
    setContentView( R.layout.activity_main );


    ArrayList<String> names = new ArrayList<>();
    names.add("szF_pLGmJTQC");
    names.add("QTKD3-mMZFYC");

    for (int i = 0; i<names.size(); i++){
        fetchBooks(names.get( i ));

    }

}


private void fetchBooks(String query) {

    client = new MyBookClient();
    final ArrayList<String> authors = new ArrayList<>(  );
    final ArrayList<String> titles = new ArrayList<>(  );
    final ArrayList<String> image = new ArrayList<>(  );
    MyBook books = new MyBook();
    client.getBooks( query, new JsonHttpResponseHandler(){
        @Override
        public void onSuccess(int statusCode, Header[] headers, JSONObject response){
            if(response!=null){
                MyBook books = MyBook.fromJson(response);

                authors.add(books.getAuthor());
                titles.add(books.getTitle());
                image.add(books.getCoverUrl());

                RecyclerView recyclerView = findViewById(R.id.rvAnimals);
                LinearLayoutManager horizontalLayoutManager
                        = new LinearLayoutManager(MainActivity.this, LinearLayoutManager.HORIZONTAL, false);
                recyclerView.setLayoutManager(horizontalLayoutManager);
                adapter = new MyRecyclerViewAdapter(MainActivity.this, authors, titles,image);
                adapter.setClickListener(MainActivity.this);
                recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);

                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "You clicked " + books.getAuthor(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        }
    });
}
```

However, it causes the adapter to clean the previous view and add on it the current.

The code of the adapter is added below:

```
public class MyRecyclerViewAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<MyRecyclerViewAdapter.ViewHolder> {

    private List<String> mViewAuthor;
    private List<String> mTitles;
    private List<String> mimages;
    private LayoutInflater mInflater;
    private ItemClickListener mClickListener;
    private Context mContext;

    MyRecyclerViewAdapter(Context context, List<String> authors, List<String> titles, List<String> image) {
        this.mInflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
        this.mViewAuthor = authors;
        this.mTitles = titles;
        this.mimages = image;
        this.mContext = context;
    }

    @Override
    @NonNull
    public ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View view = mInflater.inflate( R.layout.recyclerview_item, parent, false);
        return new ViewHolder(view);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull ViewHolder holder, int position) {

        String color = mViewAuthor.get(position);
        String animal = mTitles.get(position);
        String image = mimages.get( position);
        holder.tvAuthor.setText(color);
        holder.tvTitle.setText(animal);

        Picasso.with(mContext).load(Uri.parse(image)).error(R.drawable.ic_nocover).into(holder.ivBookCover);
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return mViewAuthor.size();
    }

public class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder implements View.OnClickListener {
        TextView tvAuthor;
        TextView tvTitle;
        ImageView ivBookCover;

        ViewHolder(View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            tvAuthor = itemView.findViewById(R.id.tvAuthor);
            tvTitle = itemView.findViewById(R.id.tvTitle);
            ivBookCover = itemView.findViewById(R.id.ivBookCover);
            itemView.setOnClickListener(this);
        }

        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            if (mClickListener != null) mClickListener.onItemClick(view, getAdapterPosition());
        }
    }

    public String getItem(int id) {
        return mViewAuthor.get(id);
    }

    public void setClickListener(ItemClickListener itemClickListener) {
        this.mClickListener = itemClickListener;
    }

    // parent activity will implement this method to respond to click events
    public interface ItemClickListener {
        void onItemClick(View view, int position);
    }

}
```

and the code of MyBook is:

```
public class MyBook implements Serializable {
    private String author;
    private String title;
    private String bookid;
    private String rating;

    public String getTitle() {
        return title;
    }

    public String getAuthor() {
        return author;
    }

    public String getId() {
        return bookid;
    }

    public String getRating(){
        return rating;
    }


    public static MyBook fromJson(JSONObject jsonObject) {
        MyBook book = new MyBook();
        try {

            JSONObject volumeInfo = jsonObject.getJSONObject( "volumeInfo" );
            book.title = volumeInfo.has("title") ? volumeInfo.getString("title") : "";
            book.author = getAuthor(volumeInfo);
            book.bookid = jsonObject.has("id") ? jsonObject.getString("id") : "";
            book.rating = volumeInfo.has("averageRating") ? String.valueOf(volumeInfo.getDouble("averageRating")) : "0";
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            return null;
        }
        return book;
    }

    private static String getAuthor(final JSONObject jsonObject) {
        try {
            final JSONArray authors = jsonObject.getJSONArray("authors");
            int numAuthors = authors.length();
            final String[] authorStrings = new String[numAuthors];
            for (int i = 0; i < numAuthors; ++i) {
                authorStrings[i] = authors.getString(i);
            }
            return TextUtils.join(", ", authorStrings);
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            return "";
        }
    }

}
```

Is there any way that I call `setadapter` I will also define the `position` where I want to view to be added?

something like:

```
fetchBooks(names.get( i ), i);
```

where the second parameter `i` is the position inside the adapter so I could get in position i=0 the first result then at i=1 the second result.

or is there just a way I can return books from `fetchBooks` class?

Thank you

Comment: please post your adapter code if possible

Answer (score 1):

> However, it causes the adapter to clean the previous view and add on it the current.

As I understand that you are trying to add query results into your RecyclerView list, but the problem is that it removes the old/previous query result from the list while adding the new one. and you need to keep all the results. Please correct me if that is wrong.

This behavior might be due to instantiating new adapter each time you get a new query result inside `onSucess()` method. So you can avoid that by transfering this part of code into `onCreate()` method; and then for each onSuccess() call, you can just call `adapter.notifyDataSetChanged()` to notify the adapter that it source of data is changed, so update yourself.

This also requires us not to instantiate the adapter with new data, but just add new method to the adapter to update lists with `.addAll()` method.

So changes:

```
MyRecyclerViewAdapter adapter;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate( savedInstanceState );
    setContentView( R.layout.activity_main );

    ArrayList<String> names = new ArrayList<>();
    names.add("szF_pLGmJTQC");
    names.add("QTKD3-mMZFYC");

    RecyclerView recyclerView = findViewById(R.id.rvAnimals);
    LinearLayoutManager horizontalLayoutManager
            = new LinearLayoutManager(MainActivity.this, LinearLayoutManager.HORIZONTAL, false);
    recyclerView.setLayoutManager(horizontalLayoutManager);
    adapter = new MyRecyclerViewAdapter(MainActivity.this, new ArrayList<>(), new ArrayList<>(), new ArrayList<>());
    adapter.setClickListener(MainActivity.this);
    recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);


    for (int i = 0; i<names.size(); i++){
        fetchBooks(names.get( i ));
    }

}


private void fetchBooks(String query) {

    client = new MyBookClient();
    MyBook books = new MyBook();
    client.getBooks( query, new JsonHttpResponseHandler(){
        @Override
        public void onSuccess(int statusCode, Header[] headers, JSONObject response){
            if(response!=null){
                MyBook books = MyBook.fromJson(response);

                adapter.addBooks(books.getAuthor(), books.getTitle(), books.getCoverUrl());

                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "You clicked " + books.getAuthor(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        }
    });
}
```

**and add below method to adapter code**

```
public void addBook(String author, String title, String image) {
    this.mViewAuthor.add(author);
    this.mTitles.add(title);
    this.mimages.add(image);
    this.notifyDataSetChanged();
}
```

I am all welcome if you need further help

Comment: Thank you very much for the answer. You understood me correctly. One thing is that types are incompatible since books.getAuthor for example, is a String while in addbooks it requires List. Added MyBook aswell.

Comment: @Ben sorry man, my fault.. you can replace addAll() in your adapte rwith add() please let me know the result; I updated the answer though for more clarifiaction

Comment: sorry mate, no errors however adapter won't show any result. It is blank.

Comment: :( let me check again

Comment: I have tested this in a simple example and it works; I am not sure what is going wrong here; but as a suggession why not you add title, author, and image into a single Model/POJO class which you could just add a single list of it in the adapter?

Comment: I have probably wrote something wrong in code and fined it. It shows the results however it shows it like before, it overwrites the first result and puts on it the second so the final result is only the second instead of 2 views. I do get adapter containing in size of 2 but it still overwrites =[

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/200134/discussion-between-ben-and-zain).